# Не работает Binding в UserControl [WPF]

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, catel

Есть кастомный UserControl со своими стилями и полем IsTurnedOn.
Контрол должен при двойном клике менять IsTurnedOn на !IsTurnedOn.

```
    namespace DCNClient.Shell.Controls
    {
        using Catel.Windows.Controls;
        using System.Windows;
        using System.Windows.Input;
        using Catel.MVVM.Views;
        using System;
        using Catel.MVVM;

        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for ToggleButton.xaml.
        /// </summary>
        public partial class ToggleButton : UserControl
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ToggleButton"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            public ToggleButton()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            [ViewToViewModel(MappingType = ViewToViewModelMappingType.TwoWayViewWins)]
            public bool IsTurnedOn
            {
                get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTurnedOnProperty); }
                set { SetValue(IsTurnedOnProperty, value); }
            }
            public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTurnedOnProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("IsTurnedOn", typeof(bool), typeof(ToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
    <catel:UserControl x:Class="DCNClient.Shell.Controls.ToggleButton"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                       xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
                       xmlns:debug="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=System">
        <!-- Content -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="37" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Label
                                    Margin="0"
                                    Padding="0"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                    Background="#010000"
                                    Foreground="#FEFEFF"
                                    FontSize="12">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Label>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTurnedOn}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Откл" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTurnedOn}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Вкл" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Button>
                <Button.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ToggleCmd}" MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" />
                </Button.InputBindings>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </catel:UserControl>
```

Теперь вызываю его так

```
        <ctrls:ToggleButton IsTurnedOn="{Binding Path=IndividualSpeechTimerState, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Проблема в том, что ToggleButton не принимает начального значения из IsTurnedOn

Использую Catel, вот ViewModel ToggleButtonViewModel

```
namespace DCNClient.Shell.Controls
{
    using Catel.Data;
    using Catel.MVVM;
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    /// <summary>
    /// UserControl view model.
    /// </summary>
    public class ToggleButtonViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ToggleButtonViewModel"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public ToggleButtonViewModel()
        {
            ToggleCmd = new Command(OnToggleCmdExecute);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the title of the view model.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The title.</value>
        public override string Title { get { return "ToggleButton"; } }

        public Command ToggleCmd { get; private set; }
        private void OnToggleCmdExecute()
        {
            IsTurnedOn = !IsTurnedOn;
        }

        public bool IsTurnedOn
        {
            get { return GetValue<bool>(IsTurnedOnProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsTurnedOnProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly PropertyData IsTurnedOnProperty = RegisterProperty("IsTurnedOn", typeof(bool), setParent: false, createDefaultValue: null);
        // TODO: Register models with the vmpropmodel codesnippet
        // TODO: Register view model properties with the vmprop or vmpropviewmodeltomodel codesnippets
        // TODO: Register commands with the vmcommand or vmcommandwithcanexecute codesnippets
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [ViewToViewModel(MappingType = ViewToViewModelMappingType.ViewModelToView)]
    public bool IsTurnedOn
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTurnedOnProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsTurnedOnProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTurnedOnProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsTurnedOn", typeof(bool), typeof(ToggleButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnIsTurnedOnChanged));

    private static void OnIsTurnedOnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = d as ToggleButton;
        var vm = btn.ViewModel as ToggleButtonViewModel;
        if(vm.IsTurnedOn != btn.IsTurnedOn)
            vm.IsTurnedOn = btn.IsTurnedOn;
    }
```

Comment: Чисто реплика. Это какая-то адова смесь из фишек фреймоворка и DependencyProperty вводит меня в ступор. Зачем!? Зачем это все? Почему и зачем нужен этот фигов Фреймворк, когда можно спокойно работать с обычными свойствами, `INotifyPropertyChanged` и `ICommand`, но мыши продложали есть кактус.

Comment: Чтобы пользоваться другими его функциями которые упрощают код, но в данном случае усложняют, конечно

Comment: Можете привести пример того как сильно упрощает работу фреймворк? Для команд достаточно один раз написать класс `RelayCommand`, для свойств достаточно один раз написать `BindingBase` класс и потом наследовать от него вьюмодели проекта. И эти два класса `RelayCommand` и `BindingBase` кочуют из проекта в проект. Это все, что в принципе требуется самостоятельно добавить, все остальное есть "из коробки" для реализации в проекте подхода MVVM подхода. Ну, и зачем Фреймворк?